# How to avoid opening the original macro file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created VBA coding in a workbook and created a macro button so that the vba code will be available to other workbooks.

But while running the vba code using macro button in other workbooks the original file opens again.

Is there a way to avoid opening the original file?

Comment: Create an [AddIn](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk003NO82-GytvRpNZA08-Xjhi7-rvw:1623110501073&q=vba+create+add+in&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNxOPm3YbxAhXayDgGHYn7D68QBSgAegQIARAw&biw=1920&bih=10670)

Comment: Convert your code to an AddIn, note you may need to change some of your code to get/action the activeworkbook instead of static named.